# disable modal on mobile boostrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4

Can we disable Modals on mobile devices?

I've looked at other threads but since just started scripting I couldn't quite figure it out also, I don't know how to use jquery, if this would be necessary.

Here is my script.

```
<div class="col-sm" >

                <input type="image" src="horse.png" class="img-thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".horseModal-modal-lg">

                <div class="modal fade horseModal-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="horse.png" id="imageSize">
                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to simply not show the modal toggle on mobiles:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary d-none d-sm-inline-block" 
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#yourModal">
  Launch modal
</button>
```

Notice `d-none d-sm-inline-block` classes on the button. Depending on what `display` value you want on the modal toggle when it's rendered, you might want to change that to `d-sm-flex` `d-sm-block` or `d-sm-inline`.

If you want to start showing the modal from `768px` up (as opposed to `545px` up) use `d-md-*` classes. Or `d-lg-*` to start showing it from `992px` up.

---

A worse alternative would be to wrap the entire modal in a similar element

```
<div class="d-none d-sm-block"> 
   your modal markup here
</div>
```

... but afaik triggering a modal will enable the modal backdrop anyway.

---

An even worse alternative is to use a library that checks whether or not current device is mobile and prevent the opening of the modal programmatically.